# Salesforce Connected Canvas App Signed Request in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, canvas

I have a Salesforce Connected App using Salesforce Canvas and the signed request method. The signed request is received decoded and access token used without issue in my developer org. I have since packaged the app and installed in a Sandbox environment, when I then load the canvas app, the access token appears invalid. I make a request to grab a list of reports using the access token and receive an 'Invalid Session' response.

Does anybody have experience with packaging Canvas Apps who may be able to help with the above?

Comment: i know it is an old question, iam facing the same issue, it works fine on my developer account but when i install the package on sandbox it doesn't get the signed request. did you solve the issue? if yes do you remember how? Thank you

Comment: Check your Connected App Managed OAuth Policy settings - they may have been adjusted on the installation on a different org (i.e. "Admin Approved" going to "User approved", etc)